Tutte polynomial for the wheel graph on 6 vertices?
Say that you are sitting an exam and the first question of a problem is to find the Tutte polynomial of the wheel graph $W_6$ ( joining a vertex with the cycle $C_6$ ). The other questions being about deducing the chromatic polynomial or the number of spanning trees. Making the first question also look like it must require a straight forward answer.
You know the recursion formula for those graphs but it won't be practical to use it since you will need first to prove it and derive the closed form formula.
So you think, ok, let me do contraction-deletion, but then you spend 30 minutes just to find the Tutte polynomial of a small branch of that huge contraction-deletion tree.
So you think, this must be done another way.
Other possibilities to explore are

Contraction-deletion in a way to obtain separable graphs and use the product formula?

Use the general formula for Tutte polynomial involving the subsets $S\subseteq E(W_6)$ , then list all those subsets?


Or maybe another way?
How would you answer this question if being faced with in a exam or a quiz?

Are you sitting in an exam?

Lol! This question is a practical one, what help could it be for you to know that the solution is out there published in a paper, when you are asked by a genie to produce an answer quickly if you want him to grant you the three wishes. You tell him the recursion formula but he is not satisfied with it. In fact, he wants to see the polynomial term by term!
